# App pushed to heroku still shows standard index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, deployment, heroku

I went through the steps to install git and the heroku gem and successfully pushed my app to heroku.
The problem is, it shows a standard "You're Riding Ruby on Rails" page even though the local app I have has routes set up to root to a certain controller/page. I have also deleted the index.html page from /public.

Any idea why this is happening? I suspect I might needed to switch from development to deployment somehow but still, I deleted the index.html, why is it still showing up on heroku?

EDIT: Going to mysite.heroku/login and other pages I've created works fine for some reason, so nevermind on the deployment thing.

Comment: Did you remove `public/index.html` from git with `git rm`, or just from your working directory? What does `git status` say?

Comment: You should post this as an answer so that I can give it the credit it deserves :) 

I didn't realize that you needed to do that, I figured git push heroku master would handle which files have been erased and which haven't been.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

When you're using git and delete a file, that file is not automatically removed from the git repo. So when you `git push heroku` the file still exists and gets pushed to Heroku.

You can tell if this is the case with `git status`, which will show something like:

```
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       deleted:    public/index.html
```

In order to remove the file, you need to use [`git rm`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm). In this case you need to do something like:

```
git rm public/index.html
git commit -m "Removed public/index.html"
```

which will remove the file from the current branch.

Now when you do

```
git push heroku
```

the file won't be included, and so you'll be routed to the controller as specified in routes.rb.

Comment: You can also just do `git commit -am "message"` and that takes care of deleted files.

Comment: for what its worth i do a git add . and then a git add -u  but user preference i guess

Answer (score 2):

I always use git commit -am "message". That prevented the above problem (which would have definitely happened), and I don't know of any reason not to use -am.

EDIT: Also, be sure to use `git add .` when you have new files to add.

So, my process is:

```
git status (to see what has changed)
git add . (if there are new files I want to add to repository)
git commit -am "This is the comment"
git push (to github)
git push heroku (--app app-name if there is more than one app connected to this repository)
```