# deploying to heroku -- can't get rid of the "welcome to rails" default page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I made a very simple rails app on local host and deleted public/index.html and changed the :root route to another page. It worked fine, but when I deployed to heroku, that index.html page shows up "Welcome Aboard, you're riding ruby on rails"

How can I get rid of that in Heroku? Why is it there?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Did you make sure to remove public/index.html from your git repo that you're pushing as well?

```
git rm public/index.html
git add -u
git commit -m "Removed index.html"
```

Comment: More info on this topic is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351182/app-pushed-to-heroku-still-shows-standard-index-page

Comment: For those that have done this, and there is still a problem: rake tmp:cache:clear