# Deploying an existing Rails app to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm new to Rails and I'm trying to deploy an existing Rails app to AWS Elastic Beanstalk.
But all I'm getting is just the "Congralutions Page"
(FYI: I'm able to run the app on "localhost:3000" using "rails server" )

I followed the instructions indicated in:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Ruby_rails.html

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Here's what I did:

```
# cd /var/www/myapp
# bundle update
# bundle install
# git init 
# git add .
# git commit -m "Initial commit"
# eb init
 // .....configuration
 // ..
# eb start
# git add .gitignore && git commit -m "Ignore .elasticbeanstalk from Git"
# git aws.push
# eb status --verbose

Retrieving status of environment "pb03-env".
URL     : pb03-env-biyaffm422.elasticbeanstalk.com
Status  : Ready
Health  : Green
Environment Name:       pb03-env
Environment ID:         e-mpnrf7js5g
Solution Stack:         32bit Amazon Linux running Ruby 1.9.3
Version Label:          git-5d8712738fd03dee0d5e6a8782055089e028f22d-1364429448649
Date Created:           2013-03-27 23:48:49
Date Updated:           2013-03-28 00:14:30
Description:            None

RDS Database: AWSEBRDSDatabase | aazyq.c0pga7irhsn.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306
Database Engine:        mysql 5.5.27
Allocated Storage:      5
Instance Class:         db.t1.micro
Multi AZ:               False
Master Username:        ebroot
Creation Time:          2013-03-27 23:53:41
DB Instance Status:     available
```

Answer (score 4):

I found out what was happening. It was a "git" problem.

It is a similar problem indicated in the following post:
[deploying to heroku -- can't get rid of the "welcome to rails" default page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323987/deploying-to-heroku-cant-get-rid-of-the-welcome-to-rails-default-page)  Except it wass for Heroku.

Anyway, This is what I did to solve it:

```
git rm public/index.html
git commit -m "Removed public/index.html"
git aws.push
```

Comment: Nice, I was looking for the answer.. good job sir. Thanks. Mark it as the answer.